# Convert date string to pd.to_datetime object python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a string of the format:

```
2013-07-22 00:00:00
```

I need to convert this to a datetime object using pd.to_datetime. However, I keep getting errors. This is what I tried:

```
data['date_object'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_as_string'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please edit your question to include those.

Comment: That should've worked, and it certainly works on that example, if you get errors then include them in your question as you probably have malformed data. If you have duff data you can convert the duff dates to `NaT`: `data['date_object'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_as_string'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')`

Comment: I used `errors = 'coerce'` and it worked. So I could go back and fix the dates that had the errors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following is working fine in pandas 0.17+.

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO 
>>> st = """  
... date_as_string 
... 2013-07-22 00:00:00
... 2013-07-23 00:00:00
... 2013-08-22 00:00:00
... """
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st))
>>> df
        date_as_string
0  2013-07-22 00:00:00
1  2013-07-23 00:00:00
2  2013-08-22 00:00:00
>>> data = df
>>> data['date_object'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_as_string'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> data
        date_as_string date_object
0  2013-07-22 00:00:00  2013-07-22
1  2013-07-23 00:00:00  2013-07-23
2  2013-08-22 00:00:00  2013-08-22
>>>
```

If you can put enough data and code to reproduce your error we can debug the reason. Otherwise, a quick fix is to `coerce` the error as follows:

```
data['date_object'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_as_string'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',  errors='coerce')
```